# Accessing a remote computer

Tags: windows, networking, windows-7, windows-8

Let's say I wish to connect to a remote computer through IP address, and open the shared C drive: I'll click on WinKey+r, and in the run command I type:

> \192.168.0.1\C

Now let's say this server requires username and password to log in. 
Normally, when I type the above command, I'll get a pop-up asking me to enter my username and password. Once I type the, I'm in.

What if I wanted to skip this "pop-up" and write the username and password directly in order to log in, something like:

> \user:pass@192.168.0.1\C

I tried using net use, but that doesn't answer my needs, as I wish to actually open drive C in my windows explorer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always just create a shared drive mapping to the C$ of the other computer. Save your login info when you create the drive.

OR

Create the same login on both computers. Windows attempts to login with your current username/password if it fails then prompts for a different username/password.

Note: either way, if you use option 1) then that user must be an admin on the computer you are connecting to. if using option 2) then you're newly created account must be an admin.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a small batch script and add it to your path, add the lines below into a file called for example `mapc.bat` and copy it into the `system32` directory:

```
@echo off
net use x: \\%1\C /user:%2 %3
explorer x:
```

Now you should be able to map a share and open it in explorer by simply typing the following into your console:

```
mapc <address> <username> <password>
```